# Turtle start and end screen ideas

Tags: python, tkinter, screen, turtle-graphics

I am kind of stuck on how to incorporate a start screen with the game information and an end screen with the game results and an option to restart the game?

I tried to write the text and then restart the screen but the text does not show up. I do not know if I can create multiple screen instances or am I missing something?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: `turtle` can be good to draw simple figures. For games better is PyGame or at least `tkinter`.

Comment: Yeah i know theres better options out there. I think i can use tkinter. This is a part of a homework so i have everything predetermined. How would i go about it using tkinter?

Answer (score 1):

A simple interface, if you're using Python 3, is the `textinput()` (and `numinput()`) command that was added to turtle:

```
textinput(title, prompt)
    Pop up a dialog window for input of a string.

    Arguments: title is the title of the dialog window,
    prompt is a text mostly describing what information to input.

    Return the string input
    If the dialog is canceled, return None.

    Example:
    >>> textinput("NIM", "Name of first player:")
```

This can both announce the game results and ask if the user wants to play again.  Not very sophisticated but might work as a stand-in while you work on the logic of restarting the game anew.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `turtle.write(text)` then you can use tkinter to put buttons on the turtle screen. Alternatively, there is a really easy GUI for Python called [EasyGUI](http://easygui.sourceforge.net).

Install using:

```
pip install easygui
```

Usage:

```
import easygui
yn = easygui.ynbox('Game over', 'Continue?', ('Yes', 'No'))
if yn == 'Yes':
    Startover()
```